# Add some QWidget over a QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt

How do I add a `QButton` on the bottom right corner of a `QOpenGLWidget`?

Comment: What have you tried?  How would place a `QPushButton` at the bottom right corner of any other `QWidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The geometry property holds the geometry relative to it's parent excluding frame.**

Calculate the position for your child widget relative to the parent widget geometry.

And then set the geometry using `setGeometry`.

A rough pseudo code is below, (*Which is untested and just for Idea. The geometry calculation also may not be correct. But gives you an idea to achieve your goal*).

Look into comments for details.

```
//YOUR OPENGL WIDGET
QOpenGLWidget *pOpenGL =  new QOpenGLWidget(<<PARENT WINDOW>>, <<FLAGS>> );

//THE BUTTON YOU ARE TRYING TO ADD. ESTABLISH PARENT CHILD RELATION
QPushButton *pButton = new QPushButton(pOpenGL);

//THIS STEP IS IMPORTANT TO SET THE LOCATION
//CALCULATE THE GEOMETRY POSITION RELATIVE TO PARENT WIDGET 
//JUST FOR YOUR IDEA. MAY NEED TO DO SOME PROPER CALCULATIONS
pButton->setGeometry(pOpenGL->x(),pOpenGL->y()-(pOpenGL->height()-20),10,20);

//THEN SET THE CENTRAL WIDGET
setCentralWidget(pOpenGL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function move :

```
QOpenGLWidget *openglWdg =  new QOpenGLWidget();
QPushButton  * btn = new QPushButton(openglWdg);
btn->move(0 , 0);
```